# Submit form using a link on JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I want to submit a simple form, but instead of using a button, I want to do it through a link. Since I'm not using JSF, I cannot use the `h:commandLink` component. I do not know how to do it in plain JSP/HTML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Use CSS to style the button to look like a link.

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="link" class="link">
   ```

   with for example

   ```
   .link {
       margin: 0;
       border: 0;
       background: none;
       overflow: visible;
       color: blue;
       cursor: pointer;
   }
   ```
2. Or, use JavaScript to grab the form and submit it.

   ```
   <form id="formid">
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formid').submit()">link</a>
   </form>
   ```

   It only won't work in browsers with JS disabled. It's however what JSF `h:commandLink` is doing under the covers (JSF components just generates plain HTML/CSS/JS after all, the webbrowser doesn't understand anything else).

Comment: I have a small problem using the second aproach. I have a simple table, and on each line i have a delete link passing the ID as hidden field. But instead of deleting the line i cliked, it deletes the first line of the table.

Comment: You're apparently passing the wrong ID or sending **all** ID's and picking only the first one. Each row/link should have its own form with a single hidden field.  If you stucks, ask a new question. This is completely unrelated to your initial question.

Comment: Nevermind, i was given all forms the same name, and submiting it, so it will always get the same form haha