# A anchor as submit button with value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This may seem like a duplicate question but I have googled and search stackoverflow how an a anchor tag would act like as a submit that would fit on the website that I am trying to do.

I have this code on my right panel navigation:

```
<div class="content clearfix">
<div class="left_column">
    <div class="product_menu">
        <? if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1) {
        $customer_panel = '
        <div class="customer_nav">
        <h1 class="customer_nav_name">Hello ' .  $_SESSION['fname'] . ',</h1>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Update Information</a></li>
            <li>
            <!-- this is where i would like the signout button to act as a submit
                 i have left it plane to start from scratch -->
                <a href="">Sign Out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>';

        echo $customer_panel;
        }?>
        <h2><span>Product Categories</span></h2>
        <ul id="prod_nav" class="clearfix">

            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Processed Meat</span></a></li>
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Ready Made</span></a></li>
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Siomai &amp; Siopao</span></a></li>
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>English Pork Snacks</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is my usual code when i use a submit button and not an anchor tag to make a POST method:

```
if(isset($_POST['signout'])) { // logout button
// Clear and destroy sessions and redirect user to home page url.
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
// Redirect to where the site home page is located -- Eg: localhost
header('Location: http://localhost/');
}
```

I have read many of this questions but I don't know jQuery or how to achieve this using javascript.

I also tried using this solution:

```
<form id="signout" action="index.php" method="post">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('signout').submit();">Sign Out</a>
<input type="hidden" name="signout" value="signout"/>
</form>
```

that I kinda found from [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169027/how-can-i-submit-a-post-form-using-the-a-href-tag/).

The problem about this is that if I include the `onclick=""` , the whole page does not show. but if i remove it, the page comes back to normal. - it doesn't work inside an `<li>` element.

It might sound basic, but it would help me and other new starters to understand how to make it possible. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Actually you want to submit a form using javascript?

Comment: Yes, but I just started developing and I'm not really good at javascript , i tried the onclick but this disabled the succeeding content of the page to be loaded when i put it inside the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**STEP 1 :**
Put the following scripts in your html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.signout-btn').click(function() {
        $('#signout').submit();
    });
})
</script>
```

**STEP 2 :**

Add an attribute `class="signout-btn"` to anchor tags, which you want to trigger the form submission.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil.. thanks, but do i still need a `<form>` tag for this? do i put `<input type="hidden">` still? would it be possible to elaborate more on the step 2 process? give the complete code that I should put inside the `<li>` tag? thank you.

Comment: It is necessary to put the `<form>` tag with `<input type="hidden">`. You can place this form anywhere in your html file.

Step 2: use this code, <li><a href="#" class="signout-btn">Sign Out</a></li>

Comment: Hi, i have tried all of this but nothing seems to be happening. :(

Comment: Make sure that, there is no js errors while clicking on the anchor tag. Check it in console panel of firebug