# How to add a link to a button in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the sign in template, but I'm not sure how to add a link when the submit button is successful. Right now the [template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/) blocks non-emails. Which is what I need.

But when the email check passes I want it to go to another web page.

Here is the line:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

I tried wrapping it with a `<a>` tag and it seemed to work once, but never again, which has me thinking that maybe a `button` tag shouldn't be wrapped with an `a` tag?

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Sign in</a>`

Comment: That skips the email check though... =( It will go to the link I put in instead of checking whether or not a valid email was entered.

Comment: Generally a form will submit to a script (PHP, ASP or something else) which will deal with the values passed from the form and then return feedback to the user and redirecting them to a thank you page or whatever as well as storing the submitted data somewhere. Bootstrap doesn't provide this functionality. A button shouldn't be wrapped in an anchor tag.

Comment: I'm confused. @BillyMoat if you click the temple link in the question then click "Submit" you see a little bubble saying that you have to enter a username. When I wrap the button in the link, it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: Unless you use JavaScript an `a` element can not submit a form, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169027/how-can-i-submit-a-post-form-using-the-a-href-tag

Answer (score 1):

First of all i do not understand why your can not have an `action` attribute that sends your data to send your form? AFAIK the HTML5 email validator runs before the form submit event. So you can use the following (jquery) code to [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/506004) the form to any other page:

```
$('.form-signin').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
alert('redirect to:' + $(this).data('http://www.test.com/')); 
return false;}
);
```

Notice that i use `$(this).data('http://www.test.com/')` with `<form class="form-signin" role="form" data-redirect-url="http://www.test.com/">`.