# Using <a href> to link to a form in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to link  to a form using only HTML/CSS? I am still a beginner in web dev and have not yet started on JavaScript or JQuery.
So what I want to do is,

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <a href="??" target="_parent">
       <li class="toggle1">Guest</li>
     </a>
     <a href="??">
       <li class="toggle2">Owner</li>
     </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

...in the  tags in the  I want to link to a form which has elements like First name, Last name etc, such that when I click on "Guest" the form for the guest should appear and likewise for "Owner"

Comment: Maybe this will help you. If you can give us more code.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170398/1515686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is! Make the href tags to `#guestform` and `#ownerform`. Then, make each form's id attribute those values (guestform and ownerform). This looks like so:

```
<div>
<ul>
 <a href="#guestform">
   <li class="toggle1">Guest</li>
 </a>
 <a href="#ownerform">
   <li class="toggle2">Owner</li>
 </a>
</ul>
</div>

<form id="guestform">...</form>

<form id="ownerform">...</form>
```

Then, in the css, do the following:

```
form {
    display:none;
}

form:target {
    display:block;
}
```

Hope this helped you!

**EDIT:** As [sdcr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483779/sdcr) said, the `a` tag should be inside the `li`, and not the other way around for it to be semantically correct. It *should* be like this instead

```
<div>
<ul>
   <li class="toggle1">
    <a href="#guestform">Guest</a>
   </li>
   <li class="toggle2">
    <a href="#ownerform">Owner</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, it's no valid HTML <li> must stay directly under <ul>.

Comment: A `<button>` element would be better here from a semantic point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misinterpreted your answer based on the lack of information given.

If  you don't care who the end user is, and make both forums accessable to them no matter if they're a guest or owner, you'd simply create another HTML document and link to that document (provided that your web server can serves "static" content).

For instance, say you created another file called `owner_form.html` and somewhere within the body, you had:

```
<form>
  ...
</form>
```

From your `index.html` you could link to `owner_form.html` via a `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="owner_form.html">... Contents that will redirect you</a>
```

---

**(old answer)**

No, this is not possible in only HTML and CSS.  Not even (securely & validly) with JavaScript.

HTML and CSS don't have the ability to differentiate the client using the page on their own.  And JavaScript can't securely do this either.

You should look into server-side programming.  This is where the magic would happen for you.  You can try many different frameworks / scripting languages that have web-server functionality to them, for instance, some of the popular ones are:

1. [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
2. [PHP](http://php.net/)
3. [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)
4. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)